# Error: Information entered incorrect. Try again

Tags: paypal, payflowlink

I am new to PayPal.I have published a hosted checkout page in PayPal Payflow link using Paypal manager.I tried to do a test transaction.I did't setup anything as required.I have given a test credit card no(collected from Paypal PayFlow link user guide) and exp date correctly.  But I received a following error.

**Error: Information entered incorrect. Try again.**

I tried to find the solution.But,couldn't.

Please help me to get the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a link to your checkout so that we can walk through and see what it is doing, or provide the code that you are using.  Its hard to say what the issue could be with out seeing what you are doing.

Comment: Please see the link,
http://alumnidemo-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/PaymentDemo

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see with your checkout page, is that you have your Payflow account set up to require address and CSC, but you only have your account set up to allow the CSC field to be editiable.  You would need to log into your Payflow Manager, and Service Settings > Set Up and under the Billing Information set it to allow the billing address section to be editiable.  This is probably causing your issue.  If you still get the error after making the change, I will test it again.  I was not able to get pass the checkout due to not being able to edit the billing address.